# HTACCESS URL REGEX rewrites files correctly but not minified or other files that have more than one period

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule that mostly works. My problem though is I have a lot of files that have more than one period in. I have minified files and I have general script files that look like the following:

```
jquery.dynamicform.js
bootstrap.min.js
```

I have a rewrite rule that makes use of the following REGEX:

```
([^.]+\.(jpeg|jpg|webp|webm|png|css|js))$
```

This regex works really well if there is only 1 period. The following is my tests:

```
assets/css/styles.css
assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
assets/js/bootstrap.min.js
assets/js/scripts.js
assets/js/query.dynamicform.js
```

This gives me the correct result on `styles.css` and `scripts.js` but not on `bootstrap.min.css` or `bootstrap.min.js` or `jquery.dynamicforms.js`.

Any idea on how I can get this regex to work for all these use cases?

My `RewriteRule` in particular is called like so:

```
RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(gif|jpeg|jpg|webp|webm|mp4|mp3|png|bmp|css|js|svg|bmp|woff|ttf))$ https://website.testing.dev/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(gif|jpeg|jpg|webp|webm|mp4|mp3|png|bmp|css|js|svg|bmp|woff|ttf))$ https://website.testing.dev/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
> ```

The issue with this regex is that given a request for `assets/css/bootstrap.min.css`, it will only match (and capture) `min.css`, since the regex `[^.]+` excludes dots.

So, you basically want this rule to apply for *all* requests that simply end with one of the stated file extensions and redirect to the same URL-path on the alternative domain. In this case, you could simply match the file extension and use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable in the substitution string instead. This avoids having to match the entire URL-path.

For example (simplified):

```
 RewriteRule \.(gif|jpeg|jpg|css|js)$ https://website.testing.dev%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

Note that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable already includes the slash prefix, so it is omitted in the *substitution* string.

---

Alternatively, to match *everything* (although arguably less efficient) you should match `.+` (everything) instead of `[^.]+` (everything except a dot) and then you can use a backreference in the *substitution* string, as you were doing.

For example:

```
 RewriteRule (.+\.(gif|jpeg|jpg|css|js))$ https://website.testing.dev/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```